# Access downloaded files from WSL

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Problem

To access a recently downloaded file, I need to:

- navigate to the windows download location
- `mv` file back to WSL home location

### What I've tried

- Change download location in Chrome: this is unintuitive because I'm greeted with windows style file paths `C:\`. It's unclear how to give a linux based filepath `home/geoff`

### Question

Is there an easier way to access recently downloaded files?

Comment: To get around this.. I just soft link the download folder to my user directory.  `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/BillyBob/Downloads/ ~/downloads`  After that, ~/downloads will be a valid path the the WSL side of the street and I don't have to mess with any settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easier way to access recently downloaded files?

### Solution

- we can find WSL-translated windows downloads path
- move recent download to current location

#### add this function to .zshrc or .bashrc

```bash
getRecentDownload() {
    windowsDownloadsLocation="/mnt/c/Users/<your_username>/Downloads"
    fileNameRecentDownload=$(ls -Art $windowsDownloadsLocation | tail -1)
    mv "$windowsDownloadsLocation/$fileNameRecentDownload" .
}
```

#### How to use

- `source` only required the first time used

```bash
geoff@DESKTOP-DSQFUUU:~$ source ~/.bashrc
geoff@DESKTOP-DSQFUUU:~$ getRecentDownload
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning : Although Windows utilities can easily download files
into WSL folders, do not try to download directly to these folders,
which are found under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages`.

The Microsoft article
[Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)
explains that WSL Linux uses its own metadata and not the Windows
information about the files.
This means that a file created with Windows will most likely
appear in Linux as empty and with zero permissions.

Microsoft has been working on the reciprocal compatibility of
Windows and WSL Linux, but in 2023 it seems that the route is
still long for full compatibility.

Comment: Who's most likely to have this question? My bet is linux -> windows users unfamiliar with the windows file system. This group is familiar with bash. This makes me lean towards a bash solution.

Comment: Huh? The largest user cohort by far seems to be Windows users who finally explore how to break out from their captivity without losing that warm fuzzy grip around their stuff.

Comment: @harrymc Could I recommend deletion of this answer?  I definitely didn't read it closely enough when I upvoted it recently, but the path you mentioned should *never* be used [per Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) as it will likely cause corruption of the WSL1 filesystem.  Fortunately, it just won't work in WSL2, which is, of course, the default now for most all users.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: You're right - I just tested in WSL2 and the Windows-created file appears as empty in Ubuntu. I will add a warning to my answer about it, and you may retract your upvote if you like.

Comment: Thanks for updating - I think with that change, I can leave the upvote in place ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of creating a shell function as mentioned above, but it's also possible to set your default download folder as:

```
\\wsl.localhost\DISTRIBUTION\home\USERNAME\Downloads
```

At least, that works for me in Vivaldi (Chrome-like browser).

Answer (score 1):

Old question that was bumped today, so throwing another new answer in.

The other answers each have some issues that, IMHO, make them sub-optimal for the question as it was asked:

> Is there an easier way to access recently downloaded files (from WSL)?

IMHO, the easiest way to do this is by simply creating a symlink in WSL back to your Windows download folder:

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/<windows_username>/Downloads ~/downloads
```

All of your Windows downloads will then be directly accessible in your `~/downloads` folder in WSL.

Note:  Reasons why I discourage the use of the other (current) answers:

- [Moving the file](https://superuser.com/a/1534333/1210833) after-the-fact isn't a bad option, but it's just one more step.  It also, as written, only works for the most recently downloaded file.  If you are downloading multiple files, it will have to be manually executed after each download.
- I'd like to apologize for my recent upvote on [@harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1534334/1210833).  I definitely didn't read it closely enough.  This path is (a) only available in WSL1, but even then (b) should never be used, as it will likely [cause filesystem corruption](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).
- [Changing the default download location](https://superuser.com/a/1778144/1210833) in the browser certainly works, and I do applaud the good taste of using Vivaldi, but most users probably won't want to download *all* files to WSL, only a select few.

  Also note that downloading directly to the folder from Vivaldi (from personal experience) has an interesting side-effect.  When Vivaldi (and perhaps other browsers, but I can't be sure) starts, it scans the list of recently download files and actually seems to perform some type of "read" operation on them.  If there is a file that was directly downloaded to the `\\wsl.localhost\<distro>` path, accessing that file will cause the WSL distribution itself to start.

  The only reason I noticed this was that I had the (now deprecated) `debugShell=true` WSL option set in my `.wslconfig`.  This causes a debug window to open whenever WSL starts.  It took me several days to figure out why WSL was starting shortly after rebooting my computer ;-).